# What are the results for the moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election

I thought the results would be published here.  What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are reported on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/election.

[image: screenshot]

While that page reports the result of the last two elections, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators reports all the actual moderators of the site, and when those moderators have been elected.

[image: screenshot]

While *Drupal Answers* just had its first election, there are sites like *Stack Overflow* where more than one election have been done, and the number of moderators is higher than 3.

[image: screenshot]